# VB.net How to Compare difference in years

Tags: vb.net, date

New VB coder here, trying to check if todays date is more then 10 years past a date from a grabbed database entry, and display a message if it is.

The Database is already imported and set up in the VB application H ave made, and working, I made a report to display the information.

I am guessing I need to use the Datediff but I can't seem to get it to work, Thanks.

I will give my variable name here

```
Dim Custsince as Date

'From the Database here
CustSince = CustListodr("Custsince")
```

Thanks in advance, working with dates is not my strong point.

Comment: In what way is `DateDiff` not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) directly by subtracting the dates:

```
Dim customerLength = DateTime.Now - Custsince
Dim approxYears = customerLength.TotalDays / 365
```

Comment: There is no `TotalYears` property in the `TimeSpan` structure, and as far as I can tell, there's no standard extension method for it either.  It makes sense since calculating total months and years is difficult when they aren't all the same length (leap years, etc.)

Comment: @StevenDoggart Yeah, forgot (fixed)

Comment: I simply combined both of your Answers, no worries! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If the date read from the database is already stored in a `Date` variable, you can simply subtract one date from another to get the difference.  The result of subtracting two dates is a `TimeSpan` object.  `TimeSpan` objects contain useful properties that allow you to see how long the span of time is in various units (e.g. days, hours, minutes).  For instance:

```
Dim date1 As Date = ...
Dim date2 As Date = Date.Now
Dim span As TimeSpan = date2 - date1
If span.TotalDays >= 3650 then  ' Ten years
    '...
End If
```

Alternatively, if you need to compare calendar years, rather than the actual span of time, you can compare the years from each date, like this:

```
If date2.Year - date1.Year >= 10 Then
    '...
End If
```

If the date being read from the database is stored as a string, rather than as a `Date` value, you would need to use `Date.Parse` or `Date.ParseExact` to convert the string into a `Date` value.